# POST multipart/form-data postman vs python request

Tags: python, request, postman, multipartform-data

I want to send a multipart/form-data as a post body using python request but I am not getting bad request issue.

```
import requests
headers = {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}


data = {
    "@context": "http://semantro.com/", "@type": "KiranaSearch", "actionName": "listCategoryProducts",
    "pageLimit": {"@context": "http://semantro.com/", "@type": "PageProperty", "start": 0, "end": 24},
    "data": {"@context": "http://semantro.com/", "@type": "KiranaCategory",
             "identifier": "c5394d1d5c6c4cb8-adc77dd996876dba"}
}

response = requests.post('https://merokirana.com/semantro-web-interface/query',
                         data=data, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Response

```
 {
  "statusTitle" : "ServiceUnsuccessful",
  "statusMessage" : "Invalid type of data received. The request  should have multipart query data.",
  "@context" : "http://semantro.com",
  "@type" : "RemoteServiceStatus"
}
```

But I can retrieve the required data using postman the same formdata.

[image]

Comment: Which headers does the postman adds to the request?

Comment: Content-Type, Content-Length, Host, User-Agent, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Connection

Comment: Did you try to copy these headers to you request?

Comment: Nope, they didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import http.client
import mimetypes
from codecs import encode

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("merokirana.com")
dataList = []
boundary = 'wL36Yn8afVp8Ag7AmP8qZ0SA4n1v9T'
dataList.append(encode('--' + boundary))
dataList.append(encode('Content-Disposition: form-data; name=data;'))

dataList.append(encode('Content-Type: {}'.format('text/plain')))
dataList.append(encode(''))

dataList.append(encode("{ \"@context\": \"http://semantro.com/\", \"@type\": \"KiranaSearch\", \"actionName\": \"listCategoryProducts\",\"pageLimit\": {\"@context\": \"http://semantro.com/\", \"@type\": \"PageProperty\", \"start\": 0, \"end\": 24}, \"data\": {\"@context\": \"http://semantro.com/\", \"@type\": \"KiranaCategory\",\"identifier\": \"c5394d1d5c6c4cb8-adc77dd996876dba\"}}"))
dataList.append(encode('--'+boundary+'--'))
dataList.append(encode(''))
body = b'\r\n'.join(dataList)
payload = body
headers = {
   'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary={}'.format(boundary) 
}
conn.request("POST", "/semantro-web-interface/query", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

output:

[image]

Comment: You will not receive a response with the request command.
Copy my answer. It will definitely give the desired answer.

Comment: Yes, this work. I want to debug what's the issue is. If everything fails I will use this for sure.

Comment: I believe the issue is the nested structure of the payload.

Comment: I tweaked with  your code a little bit to use it with request. Python requests do not work with nested json. Thanks for the help man.

Comment: FYI, if you want to add a file as data don't wrap it with encode()